# index.xhtml 404 error with Primefaces and Jboss

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, jsf-2.2

I'm building a new Maven application with **JBoss AS 7.1**, **jsf 2.2** and **Java7**. And no matter what, I cannot make it work. The Jboss it's runnig well, I can see the welcome page but there is no way (I try a lot) to see the my `index.xhtml` page. It gives me an **404** error all the time.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.metalacademy</groupId>
  <artifactId>MetalAcademy</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>MetalAcademy</name>
  
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>           
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is my `web.xml` on the *WEB-INF* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0">  
    <display-name>MetalAcademy</display-name>
    <!--
    <welcome-file-list>     
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>    
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> 
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>    
    </welcome-file-list>
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my `index.xhtml` on my *webapp* folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <ui:composition template="">
    </ui:composition>
    <h:head>
        <title>METAL ACADEMY</title>
    </h:head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <h:commandButton value="Search" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I think I tried everything... and now I'm stuck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If this is a new project I'd definitely suggest using at a minimum of Java 8, prefer 11, and WildFly 21.0.1.Final. That said what is the URL you're attempting to navigate to?

Comment: Hello @JamesR.Perkins, thank you for your suggestion. I will try to do it like that as soon as possible. Sorry for my delay in the answer, but I'm full of work, and working on this personal project whenever I can. Will try to do it this holidays and see what happens. Will let you know. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

404 normally means page not found. This suggests either the application isn't being deployed, or you're referencing the wrong name. Can you checked if the application is being deployed correctly, using the JBoss Admin Console?

What I am missing from the POM is the `maven-war-plugin`, otherwise how are you creating the .war that needs to be deployed?

In the web.xml file, you will need the `<welcome-file-list>` for index.xhtml (but not the others). Without it, the default initial page is index.html, but in Wildfly this gives me a "forbidden" error rather than a 404 if index.html doesn't exist.

In index.xhtml, the `ui:composition` with a blank template gives me a page error. Just remove the whole tag `<ui:composition></ui.composition>` to get started.

One further comment: JBoss provide some quickstart examples such as
https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/blob/7.1/numberguess which are useful as a reference.

Comment: Hello @Brooksie, I'm not creating the .war, just running it on server. I tryed all options for the <welcome-file-list>, included leaving only "index.xhtml". I will try removing the <ui:composition></ui.composition> tag and let you know asap. As I said to James R. Perkins in he's comment " I'm full of work, and working on this personal project whenever I can. Will try to do it this holidays and see what happens". Thank you very much for your answer, for sure it will be useful :-)

Comment: At the end I start fresh again with a brand new project and use apache tomcat server... it works for me. Couldn't make it work with Jboss